# .net 5.0: can't use serial ports

Tags: .net, serial-port, basic

I'm building an application for Windows, and I need to transfer data via serial port, but I can't figure out how to make it work.
I tried different declarations, different `imports`, but nothing.
Here are the 3 errors I get, from the 3 methods you can see in the pics:

> 'SerialPort1' is not declared. It could be inaccessible because of
> the protection level.\ 'SerialPorts' is not declared. It could be
> inaccessible because of the protection level.\ 'Ports' is not a member
> of 'MyComputer'.

Also, it doesn't signal it as an error, but I can't find `System.IO.Ports` in the 'nuGet package' folder, and it cannot be installed (and neither can its pre-requisites)

I have the latest version of the .NET framework: 5.0.100
Thanks to anyone that can help!

Imports used:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System
Imports System.IO.Ports
```

This sub is in a public class in the actual program

Sub `GetSerialPortNames()` Show all available COM ports. Get a list of serial port names.

```
    SerialPort1.Open() 'first way i tried

    Dim ports As String() = SerialPorts.GetPortNames()    'second way i tried

    ' Show all available COM ports. third way i tried
    For Each sp As String In My.Computer.Ports.SerialPortNames
        ListBox_Serial_Ports.Items.Add(sp)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 18):

Install `System.IO.Ports` directly from NuGet. It fixes the project and other issues with VS2019 and .net 5.0 that are present at the moment.

`Install-Package System.IO.Ports -Version 5.0.0`

or any higher stable [version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Ports/) at the time

Comment: Same issue and working solution with VS2022 / .net 6.0. Interesting. Are serial ports that exotic?